# How to create an object to follow my Player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:
[Gradius](https://youtu.be/b_qckgCQX8A?t=162)

In this game, orbs are following the player. How to do this in Unity where my orbs are following my Player.

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly are you having problem executing this? What have you tried before?
We need all this information to help you. 
It can be as simple as parenting the orbs game object to the player, but will that solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually, I have tried to use enqueue to save the previous position of the player. Then use Vector3.MoveTowards on the orbs. Although I didn't manage to make it work according to what I wanted to do. It keeps on following the player until they are on the same position. Unlike to what I want to do which is to have at least a distance between the player and the orb.

Yes, i think parenting the orbs to the player would work. I didn't thought of this approach. But still, I dont know how will I achieve the effect of having some distance between the player and the orbs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that i have thought is, lets say i have a player and it is holding it's previous position at start and whenever it moves lets say 5 units then we say to the object that will follow it to follow it's previous position and then we update player's previous position to it's current position and we follow same steps.

I have created a simple test scene and followed these steps :

- I have created 2 game objects called Player and FollowPlayer
- I have wrote the script below and attached it to the Player

```
public static event Action<Vector3> FollowMe;

[SerializeField] private float _followDistance;

private Vector3 _previousPosition;

private void Start()
{
    _previousPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,_previousPosition) > _followDistance)
    {
        if(FollowMe != null)
        {
            FollowMe.Invoke(_previousPosition);
        }

        _previousPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

- Then for the FollowPlayer object i have wrote the script below and attached to it

```
private void Start()
{
    Player.FollowMe += OnFollowMe;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    Player.FollowMe -= OnFollowMe;
}

private void OnFollowMe(Vector3 position)
{
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Again, this is a simple follow script same logic in the Gladius game and i am sure you can use this idea and make it more generic and usable.